# Gcc compiler optimization function inlining

Tags: c, gcc, optimization, inline, compiler-optimization

Does gcc add **atribute** in signature of function, or not?
Will these functions be compiled if it's in the same source file?

```
void*__attribute__ ((noinline)) GetCurrentIp(void) {
    some code...
}


void*GetCurrentIp(void);
void*__attribute__ ((always_inline)) GetCurrentIp(void)
```

Comment: You can also use the `gcc` command line option `-fno-inline` to get the effect of `noinline` for all functions in a given file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not. Attributes are not added to function signature, so you'll receive `error: redefinition of 'GetCurrentIp'`

The main reason is that function signatures are a characteristic of the language (`C` in this case), and not of the implementation (in this case `gcc`) that help you to match them in the expressions, so there must be no implementation dependency there.  And attributes (like the one you mention, a hint for the compiler to never expand that function inline) are directives to the compiler to generate the code as you want.  Indeed, attributes as defined by `gcc` are not a characteristic of the language, and as such **program meaning should not change by the inclusion or exclusion of these**.

Comment: Why do I receive that error if attributes are not added to function signature?
Aren't those 2 declarations and 1 implementation?

Comment: I thought that the second declaration is another implementation (you missed ; at the end of it). If that's are two declarations the code will compile successfully.

Comment: ...Gcc\Test\main.c|3|error: inlining failed in call to always_inline 'GetCurrentIp': function not inlinable|
I think this is not allowed. I think it watches attribute of first declaration.

Comment: What's gcc version? 4.9 seems to compile ok

Comment: rog.c:10:20: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before '(' token
 void* __atribute__((always_inline))GetCurrentIp(void);

Comment: @ЂорђеЖивановић misspelled `__attribute__` as `__atribute__`.

Answer (score 2):

Even if the question is about C, we can let g++ answer it (see [Function Names as Strings](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Names.html)).

`f.C`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern "C"
void *__attribute__((noinline)) GetCurrentIp(void)
{
    printf("signature of %s: %s\n", __func__, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    return __builtin_return_address(0);
}

int main()
{
    GetCurrentIp();
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
> g++ f.C
> a.out
signature of GetCurrentIp: void* GetCurrentIp()
```

So, the attribute is not part of the signature.